# Convert ANSI string to HTML JavaScript / NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to parse strings that contain ANSI escaped markup. I have not been able to find myself a NodeJS / JavaScript module that does exactly what I want it to do. Most modules only work when piped with the stdout, but I want to be able to parse any string to HTML.

The requirements for the module I'm looking are that it should be able to parse all the 8 bright and normal colors, bold, striked, underlined and italic formatting.

Answer (score 1):

[ansi-to-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-to-html) does that and returns an HTML formatted string.